# Derivation of the formula for the angle of intersecting lines

Tags: trigonometry

Consider two linear functions of the form

$$
f_i(x) = m_i x + b_i \qquad i \in \{1,2\}
$$

Where the graphs intersect in a point $P$. To calculate the angle $\theta$ between the two lines there is the following formula:

$$
\tan(\theta) = \left | \frac{m_1 - m_2}{1 + m_1\cdot m_2} \right |
$$

I know how to derive it using the trigonometric identity for $\tan(\theta_1 - \theta_2)$ as done demonstrated [here](https://www.sarthaks.com/223404/derive-the-formula-to-find-the-angle-between-two-lines-with-slopes-m1-and-m2), but I don't see how to derive the formula using elementary trigonometry directly.

So how can this formula derived more elementary (i.e. using elementary high school trigonometry and geometry), in particular without using this identity for $\tan$.

Comment: Is $\sin(x + y) = \sin x\cos y + \sin y \cos x$ and the analogous cosine identity also off limits?

Comment: Yes! I don't want to use any identity from this category!

Comment: Haven't worked it out, but a diagram like [this](https://i.imgur.com/Lc7KSDL.png) could help. You'd be trying to work out DE/AE in terms of BC/AC and DC/AC.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Where you my choose $AC$ as 1 then $CD$ is $m_1$ and $DB$ $m_2 - m_1$, but I don't see how to proceed.

Comment: May I  make observe that linking $m_i$ and the angle of the lines with the $x$-axis requires knowing $\arctan$, which is not exactly elementary?

Comment: @Bernard It only requires knowing $\tan$ as opposite over adjacent.

Comment: To have the tangent, yes, but the other way, no. Do you know by elementary ways what the angle with the $x$-axis is when the slope is $1/2$?

Comment: @Bernard: Just using $arctan$ (but no special identity with it) would also be ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with some algebra, we can do this using only this diagram

[image]

and basic triangle facts like the Pythagorean theorem. Note that $\tan\theta = y/x$. We can find $y$ directly in terms of $m_1$ and $m_2$ because triangles $BCA$ and $BED$ are similar:
$$
y = \frac{m_2 - m_1}{\sqrt{1 + m_2^2}}
$$
We can find then find $x$ from the Pythagorean theorem on $ACD$ and $AED$:
$$
x^2 + y^2 = 1 + m_1^2.
$$
Solving for $x^2$ and substituting in $y$ gives
\begin{multline}
x^2 = 1 + m_1^2 - \left(\frac{m_2 - m_1}{\sqrt{1+m_2^2}}\right)^2 = \frac{(1+m_1^2)(1 + m_2^2) - (m_2 - m_1^2)}{m_2^2 + 1}
\\ = \frac{1 + m_1^2m_2^2 + 2m_1m_2}{m_2^2 + 1} = \frac{(1 + m_1m_2)^2}{1 + m_2^2}
\end{multline}
From which we have
$$
\frac{y}{x} = \frac{m_2 - m_1}{1 + m_1 m_2}
$$
as desired.

The large number of triangle theorems means there might be a shortcut for the algebra in finding $x$, but I think this is pretty good.

Comment: Seems to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider lines $\overleftrightarrow{PR}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$ that intersect as shown below. Let the perpendiculars from $R$ and $Q$ meet $\overleftrightarrow{PQ}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{PR}$ at $O$ and $S$, respectively. Extend $\overline{OR}$ to meet the semicircles on $\overline{PQ}$ at $M$ and $N$. (By [Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem), $S$ is on a semicircle, say, the one containing $N$.) Define
$$p := |OP| \quad q := |OQ| \quad r := |OR| \quad s := |QS| \quad t := |RS| \quad u := |RP|$$

[image]

Note that $|OM|=|ON|=\sqrt{pq}$, as the figure incorporates the classic construction of the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) of $p$ and $q$. The relation also follows the chord-chord aspect of the [power of point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) $O$ with respect to the circle: $|OP||OQ|=\operatorname{pow}O=|OM||ON|$.

Now, by writing the area of $\triangle PQR$ in two ways, and likewise the power of $R$, and taking $\theta$ to be the indicated angle between our two lines, we have
$$\left.
\begin{array}{ccl}
\tfrac12r(p+q)=\tfrac12su\;&\to& s=\dfrac{r(p+q)}{u} \\[8pt]
|RS||RP|=|RM||RN|&\to& t = \dfrac{(\sqrt{pq}+r)(\sqrt{pq}-r)}{u}=\dfrac{pq-r^2}{u}
\end{array}
\right\}\to \tan\theta=\frac{s}{t}=\frac{r(p+q)}{pq-r^2}
\tag{$\star$}$$

If $\overline{PQ}$ is "horizontal", then, for the configuration shown, the slopes of $\overleftrightarrow{PR}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$ are, respectively, $m_1 := r/p$ and $m_2 := -r/q$ (note the sign change), so that $(\star)$ becomes (after dividing the numerator and denominator by $pq$)

> $$\tan\theta = \frac{\dfrac{r}{p}+\dfrac{r}{q}}{1-\dfrac{r}{p}\dfrac{r}{q}}=\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2} \tag{$\star\star$}$$

as expected. $\square$

Adjusting the diagram and the argument for the case where the lines have same-sign slopes, and/or $\angle PRQ$ is acute (so that $\theta$ is obtuse), is left as a straightforward exercise to the reader.

**Note:** The absolute value in the "full" formula is for when we prefer, specifically, the *non-obtuse* angle between the lines. The calculation in $(\star\star)$ itself isn't aware of that bias and may yield negative values.